# How profitable is it to use powers of two in the calculations?

Tags: c++, optimization

The question is whether it is possible to achieve a noticeable increase in productivity by using powers of two in multiplications and divisions, since the compiler could convert them to a shift (or it could be explicitly using a shift for this). I have a lot of multiplications by one number in my task (a coefficient that I myself entered), but I can use for example 512 instead of 500.

```
for(i=0;i<X;i++)
{
  cout<<i*512 // or i*500
}
```

or i need do it same:

```
for(i=0;i<X;i++)
{
   cout<<i>>9;
}
```

and an additional question - does it make sense to introduce a variable for the condition so that the compiler does not repeatedly read the condition again or does it do it automatically?
For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<10*K*H;i++)
{
// K and H cant change in this loop
}
```

I was trying to check it in Compulier Explorer, but it create less lines of code when i divide and no create same code when i multiply

Comment: Standard advice applies: Use a good optimizing compiler and trust it. Write understandable code. Profile before you manually optimize.

Comment: i really need optimization and i dont know how my compilator works, i write a game with some light

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. And for the second question: it's is totally unclear what you're asking. Please ask another question for this and show both codes, the one with the _"variable for the condition, you've introduced"_ and tnhe one without. Generally  when asking questions it is advised to _show_ the code instead of describing it.

Comment: In the given option, I can say second option will be more optimized one. As it is using the shift operator which most probably take care by the processor shift register and will be optimized one.

Comment: Generally these micro optimisations don't change anything. Most of the time the compilers generate better machine code than "clever" and hand optimized C code.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of g++ or clang with `-O2` optimization, it's unlikely you can do better than the compiler at optimizing. Focus on things like algorithmic complexity that can make a *huge* difference in performance.

Comment: @Sanjeev: No. If you correct the shift direction (the OP's code erroneously shifts right, which will divide instead of multiply), [the generated code is identical](https://godbolt.org/z/2kzBbb).

Comment: in general when you need to multiply with 500 then multiplying with 512 is not an optimization, but a bug. I do not understand this question

Comment: Also, if you try to be too clever by attempting to beat the compiler at the optimization game, most of the time you will end up losing.  Doing stuff with pointers, tricky logic, etc. in an attempt to "speed up the code" will just render the optimizer useless.

Comment: man i just dont know what my compilator can do, where i can see this knowledge

Comment: @Kelbon which compiler? Compiler explorer can use one of many compilers, accessible from a drop-down list above the assembly code. Select which compiler you're interested in from that list and look up its documentation.

Comment: With modern processors, multiplication of powers of 2 doesn't save any time versus non-powers of 2.  The compiler may generate a multiplication instruction for the processor.  The multiplication instruction is not optimized for powers of 2.  If it was, you may be saving nanoseconds or possibly milliseconds by this optimization.  In most applications, this is negligible compared to other big consumers of time, such as I/O.

Comment: You can always tell the compiler to print (output) an assembly language listing of the function.  Print one assembly language listing with 512, another with 520 and compare.  The truth is in the assembly language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the limit in the `for` loop, you may want to give the compiler some assistance.

Compute the limit before the loop:

```
const int limit = 10 * K * H;
for (i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
}
```

This can help when compiling with no optimizations (e.g. debug mode).  Your compiler may perform better optimizations when you increase the optimization level.

I recommend printing the assembly language for your `for` loop and comparing with the assembly language for the above code.   The truth is in the assembly language.

**Edit 1: shifting vs. multiplication**
In most processors, bit shifting is often faster than multiplication. In modern processors, the savings is in the order of nanoseconds, or possibly microseconds.

Many compilers will convert a multiplication into a bit shift, depending on the optimization level and the context.

In your example, you will probably not notice the optimization gain, because the gain will be wasted in the call to `cout`.  I/O consumes more time than the time gained by micro-optimizations.

Profiling your code will give you the best data for making these kinds of decisions.  Also read about *benchmarking* to collect better data.  For example, you may have to run your loop for 1E6 or more iterations to rule out outliers such as interrupts and task swaps.